# Is there a way to do audio conferencing rooms in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, webrtc

I'm trying to build a simple audio-conferencing app similar to Clubhouse in Flutter, but with only the very barebones. I was trying to get started with the flutter WebRTC plugin because I thought that webRTC might be a good try to see if it works, but I couldn't find a way to do audio rooms or anything. I googled for AGES. Is there a way to get this done?

Comment: you could use [agora](https://www.agora.io/) API it is simple

Comment: hmm... ok, ill give it a try